# MySQL calculate overlapping period excluding overlapping rules

Tags: mysql, datetime

I would like to calculate the period overlap in hours based on special rules.
I created a test setup, that works as long as the rules themselves don't overlap.

Example **non** overlapping rules:

```
    id  ort_name          ort_type  time_start  time_end  factor  
------  ----------------  --------  ----------  --------  --------
     1  Overtime evening  daily     18:00:00    23:59:59      1.20
     2  Overtime Night    daily     00:00:00    05:00:00      1.20
```

When the rules do overlap I need to solve this in our programming language, but I was looking for a database only solution.

Example **overlapping** rules:

```
    id  ort_name              ort_type  time_start  time_end  factor  
------  --------------------  --------  ----------  --------  --------
     1  Overtime evening      daily     18:00:00    23:59:59      1.20
     2  Overtime Night        daily     00:00:00    05:00:00      1.20
     3  Overtime Night Extra  daily     01:00:00    03:00:00      1.30
```

In the below example the users Kevin and Michael don't have overlapping rules and the result is as expected. The user Derrick is affected by rule (id) 1, 2 and 3 (overlapping rules)

Example query:

```
SELECT
    OC.ort_rule_id
    , ORT.factor
    , S.user_name
    , S.shift_id
    , S.date_start AS shift_start
    , S.date_end AS shift_end
    , ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, S.date_start, S.date_end) / 3600), 2) AS shift_duration_hours
    , GREATEST(OC.ort_date_start, S.date_start) AS overlap_start
    , LEAST(OC.ort_date_end, S.date_end) AS overlap_end
    , ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, GREATEST(OC.ort_date_start, S.date_start), LEAST(OC.ort_date_end, S.date_end)) / 3600), 2) AS overlap_duration_hours 
FROM
    shifts AS S    
INNER JOIN ort_calendar AS OC 
        ON S.date_end > OC.ort_date_start 
        AND S.date_start < OC.ort_date_end
INNER JOIN ort_rule AS ORT
    ON OC.ort_rule_id = ORT.id
WHERE
    S.date_start >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
AND
    S.date_end < '2014-12-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
ORDER BY
    S.user_name ASC, S.date_start ASC, overlap_start ASC, ORT.factor DESC
```

Output:

```
ort_rule_id  factor  user_name  shift_id  shift_start          shift_end            shift_duration_hours  overlap_start        overlap_end          overlap_duration_hours  
-----------  ------  ---------  --------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------------  -------------------  -------------------  ------------------------
          1    1.20  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00                    
          2    1.20  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 00:00:00  2014-12-10 05:00:00  5.00                    
          3    1.30  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 01:00:00  2014-12-10 03:00:00  2.00                    
          1    1.20  Kevin             2  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:00:00  9.00                  2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00                    
          1    1.20  Michael           7  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  9.50                  2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00                    
          2    1.20  Michael           7  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  9.50                  2014-12-10 00:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  0.50
```

I would like the output of my query to take into account the overlapping rules. The rule with the highest factor gets precedence above a rule with a lower factor.
The output of my query should be:

```
ort_rule_id  factor  user_name  shift_id  shift_start          shift_end            shift_duration_hours  overlap_start        overlap_end          overlap_duration_hours  
-----------  ------  ---------  --------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------------  -------------------  -------------------  ------------------------
          1    1.20  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00                    
          2    1.20  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 00:00:00  2014-12-10 01:00:00  1.00                    
          3    1.30  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 01:00:00  2014-12-10 03:00:00  2.00                    
          2    1.20  Derrick           8  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 03:00:00  2014-12-10 05:00:00  2.00                    
          1    1.20  Kevin             2  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:00:00  9.00                  2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00                    
          1    1.20  Michael           7  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  9.50                  2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00                    
          2    1.20  Michael           7  2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  9.50                  2014-12-10 00:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  0.50
```

===========

## DDL

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*Table structure for table `ort_calendar` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ort_calendar`;

CREATE TABLE `ort_calendar` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ort_rule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ort_date_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ort_date_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ort_calendar_unique` (`ort_rule_id`,`ort_date_start`,`ort_date_end`),
  KEY `ort_date_start_idx` (`ort_date_start`),
  KEY `ort_date_end_idx` (`ort_date_end`),
  CONSTRAINT `ort_period_ort_rule_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ort_rule_id`) REFERENCES `ort_rule` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=783 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `ort_calendar` */

insert  into `ort_calendar`(`id`,`ort_rule_id`,`ort_date_start`,`ort_date_end`) values (6,1,'2014-12-08 18:00:00','2014-12-08 23:59:59'),(58,1,'2014-12-09 18:00:00','2014-12-09 23:59:59'),(110,1,'2014-12-10 18:00:00','2014-12-10 23:59:59'),(266,2,'2014-12-09 00:00:00','2014-12-09 05:00:00'),(318,2,'2014-12-10 00:00:00','2014-12-10 05:00:00'),(527,3,'2014-12-09 01:00:00','2014-12-09 03:00:00'),(579,3,'2014-12-10 01:00:00','2014-12-10 03:00:00');

/*Table structure for table `ort_rule` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ort_rule`;

CREATE TABLE `ort_rule` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ort_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `ort_type` enum('daily','yearly') NOT NULL,
  `time_start` time NOT NULL,
  `time_end` time NOT NULL,
  `factor` double(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ort_name_idx` (`ort_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `ort_rule` */

insert  into `ort_rule`(`id`,`ort_name`,`ort_type`,`time_start`,`time_end`,`factor`,`deleted_by`,`deleted_date`) values (1,'Overtime evening','daily','18:00:00','23:59:59',1.20,NULL,NULL),(2,'Overtime Night','daily','00:00:00','05:00:00',1.20,NULL,NULL),(3,'Overtime Night Extra','daily','01:00:00','03:00:00',1.30,NULL,NULL);

/*Table structure for table `shifts` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `shifts`;

CREATE TABLE `shifts` (
  `shift_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pause` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`shift_id`),
  KEY `idx_date_start` (`date_start`),
  KEY `idx_date_end` (`date_end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `shifts` */

insert  into `shifts`(`shift_id`,`user_name`,`date_start`,`date_end`,`pause`) values (1,'Franck','2014-12-08 08:00:00','2014-12-08 17:00:00',30),(2,'Kevin','2014-12-09 15:00:00','2014-12-10 00:00:00',60),(3,'Michael','2014-12-10 08:00:00','2014-12-10 17:00:00',60),(4,'Franck','2014-12-31 08:00:00','2014-12-31 17:00:00',90),(5,'Franck','2015-01-01 08:00:00','2015-01-01 17:00:00',30),(6,'Franck','2014-12-07 08:00:00','2014-12-07 17:00:00',30),(7,'Michael','2014-12-09 15:00:00','2014-12-10 00:30:00',30),(8,'Derrick','2014-12-09 15:00:00','2014-12-10 06:12:27',30);

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Comment: Would love to see a good answer to this. If op has one that would be great.

Comment: @JonathanAllon It is a while back, but If I remembers correctly I solved this programmatically. Still interested in an answer though

Comment: @CecilZorg - happen to have a high-level description of how you finally solved this ... might be interesting to see if/how it might convert to SQL

Answer (score 2):

We'll start with a few assumptions/observations/limits ...

- `ort_rules` time periods do not span midnight (at least for ort_type = 'daily')
- `ort_calendar` time periods do not span midnight
- `shifts` time periods can span midnight but at most once (ie, person isn't working from day1 to day2 to day3)
- completely ignoring the `ort_rule.ort_type = {daily | yearly }` as we've only got sample 'daily' data to work with
- 'daily' rules apply for all 7 days of the week (ie, weekends are treated just like weekdays)
- don't know what version of MySQL is in use so will skip trying to do this with CTEs (not available prior to MySQL 8.0) and instead use some temp tables
- conducted my testing on 2 different fiddles, with 2 different versions of MySQL; one fiddle allows `create temp table/select/union/select` while the other doesn't allow the `union` so had to use `create temp table/insert-select`
- while a lot of this code could be included in the main query (as derived tables and/or CTEs), I've opted to use temp tables in order to allow for easier debugging

Data setups:

- copied the provided DDL, moved the create/drop commands around some to get around the 'you cannot drop a table with active FK constraints')

Build a new list of `shifts`:

```
/******************************

for shifts that span midnight, break into 2 separate shifts:
    1) date_start up to 23:59:59
    2) 'tomorrow' from 00:00:00 to date_end

split datetimes into separate date/time parts to make time comparisons a little easier later on

drag along the original shift_id, user_name, date_start/date_end (as dt_start/dt_end) so we don't
    have to join back to shifts later

*/

drop table if exists t_shifts;

create temporary table if not exists t_shifts
(shift_id    int(10) unsigned       not NULL
,user_name   varchar(20)        default NULL
,orig_start  datetime               not NULL
,orig_end    datetime               not NULL
,date_start  date                   not NULL
,time_start  time                   not NULL
,date_end    date                   not NULL
,time_end    time                   not NULL
);

insert into t_shifts (shift_id, user_name, orig_start, orig_end, date_start, time_start, date_end, time_end)

/* shifts that don't span midnight */

select  shift_id,
        user_name,
        date_start,
        date_end,
        date(date_start),
        time(date_start),
        date(date_end),
        time(date_end)
from    shifts
where   date(date_start)  = date(date_end)
and     date_start       >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
and     date_end         <= '2014-12-01 00:00:00' + interval 1 month

union

/* shifts that span midnight - create new shift for date_start - 23:59:59 */

select  shift_id,
        user_name,
        date_start,
        date_end,
        date(date_start),
        time(date_start),
        date(date_start),
        cast('23:59:59' as time)
from    shifts
where   date(date_start) != date(date_end)
and     date_start       >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
and     date_end         <= '2014-12-01 00:00:00' + interval 1 month

union

/* shifts that span midnight - create new shift for 'tomorrow' from 00:00:00 to date_end */

select  shift_id,
        user_name,
        date_start,
        date_end,
        date(date_end),
        cast('00:00:00' as time),
        date(date_end),
        time(date_end)
from    shifts
where   date(date_start) != date(date_end)
and     date_start       >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
and     date_end         <= '2014-12-01 00:00:00' + interval 1 month;
```

A key part of this solution is next ... breaking down `ort_rule` time ranges into non-overlapping time ranges.

```
drop table if exists t_time_ranges;

create temporary table if not exists t_time_ranges
(time_start    time
,time_end      time
);

insert into t_time_ranges (time_start, time_end)
select r1.time_start,
       r1.time_end
from   ort_rule r1
where  r1.time_start != r1.time_end
and not exists(select 1
               from   ort_rule r2
               where  r2.id != r1.id
               and    (    r2.time_start between r1.time_start and r1.time_end
                       or  r2.time_end   between r1.time_start and r1.time_end
                      ))

union

select r1.time_start,
       r2.time_start
from   ort_rule r1
join   ort_rule r2
on     r2.time_start between r1.time_start and r1.time_end
and    r2.id != r1.id

union

select r1.time_start,
       r2.time_end
from   ort_rule r1
join   ort_rule r2
on     r2.time_end   between r1.time_start and r1.time_end
and    r2.time_start < r1.time_start
and    r2.id != r2.id

union

select r2.time_end,
       r1.time_end
from   ort_rule r1
join   ort_rule r2
on     r2.time_end   between r1.time_start and r1.time_end
and    r2.id != r1.id;
```

And now the main event:

```
/******************************

for overlap related values we need to concatentate our
separate dates/times back into datetime values 

*/

select  or1.id         as ort_rule_id,
        or1.factor,
        dt.user_name,
        dt.shift_id,
        dt.orig_start  as shift_start,
        dt.orig_end    as shift_end,

        round( (timestampdiff(second, dt.orig_start, dt.orig_end) / 3600), 2)                 as shift_duration_hours,
        greatest(cast(concat(dt.date_start,' ',dt.r_time_start) as datetime), dt.orig_start)  as overlap_start,
        least(   cast(concat(dt.date_end  ,' ',dt.r_time_end)   as datetime), dt.orig_end)    as overlap_end,

        round( (timestampdiff(second, greatest(cast(concat(dt.date_start,' ',dt.r_time_start) as datetime), dt.orig_start), 
                                      least(   cast(concat(dt.date_end  ,' ',dt.r_time_end)   as datetime), dt.orig_end)
                ) / 3600), 2
             )  as overlap_duration_hours
from
(
select  distinct
        /* shift data */
        ts.shift_id, 
        ts.user_name,
        ts.orig_start,
        ts.orig_end,
        ts.date_start, 
        ts.time_start, 
        ts.date_end, 
        ts.time_end, 
        /* rule/time range data */
        ttr.time_start as r_time_start, 
        ttr.time_end   as r_time_end

from    t_shifts ts
left
join    t_time_ranges ttr

on      ttr.time_start between ts.time_start and ts.time_end
or      ttr.time_end   between ts.time_start and ts.time_end

) dt

join    ort_calendar oc 
on      dt.orig_start < oc.ort_date_end
and     dt.orig_end   > oc.ort_date_start 


join    ort_rule or1
on      or1.id           = oc.ort_rule_id
and     dt.r_time_start >= or1.time_start
and     dt.r_time_end   <= or1.time_end
and     or1.factor = (select max(or2.factor)
                      from   ort_rule or2
              where  dt.r_time_start >= or2.time_start
              and    dt.r_time_end   <= or2.time_end)

order by dt.user_name  asc,
         shift_start   asc,
         overlap_start asc,
         or1.factor    desc;


ort_rule_id  factor  user_name  shift_id  shift_start          shift_end            shift_duration_hours  overlap_start        overlap_end          overlap_duration_hours
-----------  ------  ---------  --------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------------------
1            1.2     Derrick    8         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00
2            1.2     Derrick    8         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 00:00:00  2014-12-10 01:00:00  1.00
3            1.3     Derrick    8         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 01:00:00  2014-12-10 03:00:00  2.00
2            1.2     Derrick    8         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 06:12:27  15.21                 2014-12-10 03:00:00  2014-12-10 05:00:00  2.00

1            1.2     Kevin      2         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:00:00  9.00                  2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00

1            1.2     Michael    7         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  9.50                  2014-12-09 18:00:00  2014-12-09 23:59:59  6.00
2            1.2     Michael    7         2014-12-09 15:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  9.50                  2014-12-10 00:00:00  2014-12-10 00:30:00  0.50
```

- derived table (dt) : join the expanded `shifts` with our non-overlapping `rules` time ranges
- join to `ort_rule` to get our `ort_rule_id/factor` values
- the sub-query (`ort_rule or2`) allows us to find the `max(factor)` that applies for a given overlap period
- the overlap values (start/end/duration) are a bit of a kludge because we need to concatenate some dates and times together into their equivalent datetime values

A couple fiddles for the above:

- [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/NHKMUR20651)
- [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/epJKiehSigSQQhoowj1wtc/9)